# Line-end agnostic diff?

Tags: macos, unix, grep, diff, utilities

I'm working on a Mac, with some fairly old files. Different files were created by different programs, so some of them end with `\r` (Mac) and some with `\n` (Unix). I want to be able to run commands like diff, grep, etc. on these files, but the ones that have `\r` are treated as one giant line. Are there versions of [diff](https://linux.die.net/man/1/diff), [grep](https://linux.die.net/man/1/grep), etc. that will work correctly with all new-lines?

ETA: I'd also like them to be Unix utilities, so I can use them in scripts, Emacs, etc...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As Jay said, Diff'nPatch seems what you are looking for. Alternatively you can convert all your '\r' line endings in '\n' in a single command like this:

```
sed -ie 's/\r/\n/' filename
```

or

```
find . | xargs -n1 sed -ie 's/\r/\n/'
```

(You may want to filter the list of files in some way in the latter case or it will be applied to all the files in all subdirectories.)

Comment: If he has any files with windows style \r\n then this will end up replacing every Windows line break with a \n\n which is probably not the desired effect.

Comment: True, but I was taking into account that he only mentioned mac and unix style line endings...

Comment: no, it's all macs, and I already had a mac2unix which was very similar (uses tr instead of sed, but yeah...)

Comment: Conscious this is an old post, but. I had to 'g' to your first command as I found that an additional return was implemented. i.e. `sed -ie 's/\r/\n/g' filename` produced the desired results whereas `sed -ie 's/\r/\n/' filename` inserted a return after each line. I'm not sure what the significance of this additional character is, but it worked for me.

Answer (score 12):

If you use `diff -w` it will ignore whitespace in the files, which is probably sufficient for your needs.

**EDIT**: just realized I misread the post the first time and you're actually looking for a diff that will work with `\r` line endings. My suggestion would be to convert the files with something like [**flip**](http://ccrma-www.stanford.edu/~craig/utility/flip/) that can convert the files to a `\n` standard format.

**EDIT 2**: Just found something that looks like what you want - [**Diff'nPatch**](http://www.versiontracker.com/dyn/moreinfo/macosx/19069):

> Diff'nPatch is a port to the Macintosh
>   of the GNU 'diff', 'patch' and 'cmp'
>   utilities. It lets you compare and
>   find differences between two files or
>   folders, collate two files, generate
>   diffs in various formats (normal,
>   context, unidiff, etc.), apply
>   patches, compare files byte by byte.
>   It can handle any type of line endings
>   (mac, unix or windows)

Comment: nope. -w just ignores whitespace IN THE LINE. it then treats the \r file as one huge line, without the \r's. the \n file is still a bunch of different lines.

Comment: it seems that the link for Diff'nPatch is now http://download.cnet.com/Diff-npatch/3000-2247_4-36909.html

Comment: I agree with Chris: I just found Jay's reply. I also had a problem with the different line endings, to the result that `diff` marked each single line of the file as difference.  I compared DOS / *X Files. `diff -uw` was the cure.

Comment: For many other programs newline is also a white space character, but diff is a line-oriented program and a newline character always ends a line. Hence the -w or --ignore-all-space option does not ignore newline-related changes; it ignores only other white space changes.

Answer (score 8):

The diff utility bundled with [OS X v10.7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_X_Lion) (Lion) has an option 'strip-trailing-cr' that does that you want. You use it like so:

```
diff -cpt a.c b.c --strip-trailing-cr
```

Comment: The options is available on Linux as well.

Comment: it will strip the cr on diff's OUTPUT, not input.

Comment: The `man` page says, "Strip trailing carriage return on *input*."

Answer (score 3):

PhpStorm's diff view's "ignore whitespace" **just works**. It automatically ignores differences in the carriage return / EOL / newline / what-have-you. You can waste your time fiddling with arcane Unix commands or whatever, or you could just get something that actually works and move forward with life.

- Using any of the above-mentioned solutions failed on OS X v10.8 (Mountain Lion) (including the one marked as the correct answer). All the download links for "Diff-npatch" failed. (I did find http://webperso.easyconnect.fr/bdesgraupes/tools.html, but I really don't like the idea of having to resort to using a diff tool that cannot be invoked from the command line and thus integrated with whatever IDE or version control system tool I might be using, like [BBEdit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BBEdit), [Sourcetree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atlassian#Acquisitions_and_product_announcements), or SmartSVN -- all of which, BTW, failed to ignore newlines with their built-in diff tool.

Yes, my newlines are \r, but so what? Arrr! If the software is too stupid to realize that \r == \n then I'm just going to use different software that *is* smart enough.

PhpStorm was the only software that had a diff tool that "just worked" -- which is what I expect Mac software to do. I expect Mac software to *just work*. I use a Mac, so I can do my job instead of learning arcane terminal commands at every turn, which are almost all poorly documented, expecting you to just understand how the commands are supposed to be formatted without any clear examples, so you never know if you're doing it wrong or if the command *simply doesn't work* just like all other bad software.

Take this example from "man diff":

> ```
>    -I RE  --ignore-matching-lines=RE
>           Ignore changes whose lines all match RE.
> ```

OK, so having read this, I have no idea what it means. There is no example of its usage. What is "RE"? It doesn't say anywhere.

Then there's this jewel:

> ```
>   --GTYPE-group-format=GFMT
>           Similar, but format GTYPE input groups with GFMT.
>
>    --line-format=LFMT
>           Similar, but format all input lines with LFMT.
>
>    --LTYPE-line-format=LFMT
>           Similar, but format LTYPE input lines with LFMT.
>
>    LTYPE is `old', `new', or `unchanged'.
>           GTYPE is LTYPE or `changed'.
>
>           GFMT may contain:
>
>    %<     lines from FILE1
>
>    %>     lines from FILE2
>
>    %=     lines common to FILE1 and FILE2
>
>    %[-][WIDTH][.[PREC]]{doxX}LETTER
>           printf-style spec for LETTER
>
>           LETTERs are as follows for new group, lower case for old group:
>
>    F      first line number
>
>    L      last line number
>
>    N      number of lines = L-F+1
>
>    E      F-1
>
>    M      L+1
>
>           LFMT may contain:
>
>    %L     contents of line
>
>    %l     contents of line, excluding any trailing newline
>
>    %[-][WIDTH][.[PREC]]{doxX}n
>           printf-style spec for input line number
>
>           Either GFMT or LFMT may contain:
>
>    %%     %
>
>    %c'C'  the single character C
>
>    %c'\OOO'
>           the character with octal code OOO
> ```

I could make no sense whatsoever of this passage. What is the "input"? Is it both files or just the "to" file or just the "from" file? What is "similar" referring to? What does "is" mean in the sentence, "GFMT 'is' LTYPE or `changed'"? Does it mean "may be replaced by"? If so then why isn't "GFMT" in quotations, brackets, etc.? Since no example is given, there is no way to know; the documentation's wording is totally ambiguous. What does "GFMT may contain"... mean? Does "contain" mean that the text replacing the acronym GFMT may contain that? Without a clear example it's completely useless.

Why even bother to write a man page if you're going to make it so cryptic and ambiguous it's useless to anyone who doesn't already know how to use the software, basically? At that point, it's not a manual; it's just a quick-reference page for the guys who wrote the software so they can remember how to use it. I guess they assume you'll just read the source-code itself if you want to know what it actually does.

My time is valuable. I'd rather just pay the money to have a piece of software that actually works correctly and has proper documentation.

Because these all failed:

```
 diff -d --strip-trailing-cr --ignore-all-space --from-file=rest.phtml test.phtml
```

...failed to ignore \r characters.

```
 diff -wd --strip-trailing-cr --ignore-all-space --from-file=rest.phtml test.phtml
```

...failed to ignore \r characters.

```
 diff -wd --suppress-common-lines --strip-trailing-cr --ignore-all-space --from-file=rest.phtml test.phtml
```

...failed to ignore \r characters.

```
 diff -wd test.phtml rest.phtml --suppress-common-lines --strip-trailing-cr --ignore-all-space
```

...failed to ignore \r characters.

```
 diff -awd test.phtml rest.phtml --suppress-common-lines --strip-trailing-cr --ignore-all-space
```

...failed to ignore \r characters.

For that matter if they were \n characters it also failed when the \n characters are added.

Where test.phtml ==

> foo

> bar

and rest.html ==

> foobar

The "diff" command always gives you something like:

> ---

> *** 1,2 **** ! foo ! bar \ No newline at end of file

> --- 1 ---- ! foobar \ No newline at end of file

... fail!

Comment: RE is a regular expression.

Comment: Quite a rant, but yes, the holy man pages are very much open to interpretation (and thus partly useless).

Answer (score 2):

The dos2unix command could be helpful in converting your files to a consistent format first.  I believe it's available for just about every platform you can think of and can run on lots of files at once.  I believe there's a package available for Mac.

Comment: There is some support for mac formatted files in dos2unix via the convmode option.  With that in mind, it may be possible to create a consistent (and separate) conversion for the purpose of diffing/grepping.

Comment: I actually wrote a mac2unix a while back, and that ended up being the bestsolution...

Comment: also, there's a command 'flip' which works for any combination!

Learn something new every day!

Answer (score 0):

I used the following quick fix, which has drawbacks (see below):

**1**: Do a diff and list only the filenames

```
diff -r -q dir1/ dir2/
```

**2**: Open and save every listed file with the editor that was used, this will change the line-endings.

**3**: Do a regular diff

Drawbacks include:

- less robust, error prone
- more work if you have lots of files

Comment: Better to automate step 2 with dos2unix or flip or something

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me:

```
diff -r --ignore-all-space dir1/ dir2/
```

I am on OS X and have mixed files from OS X and Windows.

Credit: http://www.codealpha.net/514/diff-and-ignoring-spaces-and-end-of-lines-unix-dos-eol/

Comment: This does not work. If file A contains "foo\rbar" and file B contains "foobar" they will come up as different. The point is to *ignore all white space including carriage returns!*

Comment: I think that's not right.  If you have two files with `foo<new line>bar` and `foobar`, would you not say those are different?

Comment: You're right, in this context, it is different. I actually came to this page due to searching for a way to ignore newlines when their addition is the only change to a file, so that for example prettified JSON would not be treated as different than the non-prettified form of the same JSON. Of course with something like YAML where there is no "non-prettified" form then the newline chars are vital. I should've read it more closely before commenting... too many tabs...

Comment: The link is broken (404).