# Compare/Diff two files with different line terminators

Tags: linux, macos, bash

I have two text files I wish to make sure are the same, the problem is that file1 (`SELECT_20150210.txt`) is generated on a windows platform, and file2 (`sel.txt`) is generated on a mac, so the two files have different line terminating characters even though they look the same:

The first line:

```
Eriks-MacBook-Air:hftdump erik$ head -n 1 sel.txt
SystemState 0x04    25  03:03:48.800    O
Eriks-MacBook-Air:hftdump erik$ head -n 1 SELECT_20150210.txt
SystemState 0x04    25  03:03:48.800    O
```

`cmp` says they are different:

```
Eriks-MacBook-Air:hftdump erik$ cmp sel.txt SELECT_20150210.txt
sel.txt SELECT_20150210.txt differ: char 35, line 1
```

But it's only the terminating characters that differ:

```
Eriks-MacBook-Air:hftdump erik$ head -n 1 SELECT_20150210.txt | hexdump -C
00000000  53 79 73 74 65 6d 53 74  61 74 65 09 30 78 30 34  |SystemState.0x04|
00000010  09 32 35 09 30 33 3a 30  33 3a 34 38 2e 38 30 30  |.25.03:03:48.800|
00000020  09 4f 0d 0a                                       |.O..|
00000024
Eriks-MacBook-Air:hftdump erik$ head -n 1 sel.txt | hexdump -C
00000000  53 79 73 74 65 6d 53 74  61 74 65 09 30 78 30 34  |SystemState.0x04|
00000010  09 32 35 09 30 33 3a 30  33 3a 34 38 2e 38 30 30  |.25.03:03:48.800|
00000020  09 4f 0a                                          |.O.|
00000023
```

So is there a way to `cmp` or `diff` these two file and telling `cmp` to ignore the different line terminating character? Thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/543779/line-end-agnostic-diff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sup>***ASSUMPTION:*** you don't want to alter the line-endings of the original files</sup>

To avoid creating temporary files, you could use [*process substitution*](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html):

```
diff my_unix_file <(dos2unix < my_dos_file)
diff my_unix_file <(sed 's/\r//' my_dos_file)
diff my_unix_file <(tr -d '\r' < my_dos_file)
```

<sup>***UPDATE*** (Comments converted into answer): Some improvements done thanks to [anishsane](https://stackoverflow.com/users/793796/anishsane)</sup>

Comment: @anubhava: choose any of the dos2unix methods using `tr`, `awk`, `sed`, [etc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613800/how-to-convert-dos-windows-newline-crlf-to-unix-newline-n-in-bash-script)

Comment: Don't use `<(cat filename)`, when you just wanted `filename` :P `diff my_unix_file <(tr -d '\r' < my_dos_file)`

Answer (score 2):

On OSX you can use this `diff`:

```
diff osx-file.txt <(tr -d '\r' < win-file.txt)
```

`tr -d '\r' < win-file.txt` will strip `r` from `win-file.txt`.