# How can I ignore line endings when comparing files?

Tags: diff

I am comparing two text files and I get the following result:

```
diff file1 file2 | grep 12345678

> 12345678
< 12345678
```

As you can see, the same string exists in both files, and both files were sorted with `sort`.

The line endings must be getting in the way here (Windows vs. Unix).

Is there a way to get `diff` to ignore line endings on Unix?

Comment: `diff --strip-trailing-cr file1 file2`?

Comment: @RuslanOsmanov sounds like an answer, thank you. Btw is that the same as `-w` ?

Comment: No, `-w` ignores differences in white spaces, and `"White space" characters include tab, vertical tab, form feed, carriage return, and space`. For instance, `diff a b` will show difference for `    line` and `<tab>line`, but `diff -w a b` won't

Comment: @RuslanOsmanov That's a fine explanation, would you mind to shift it to an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? *[Line-end agnostic diff?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/543779/line-end-agnostic-diff)*. Nearly 9 years prior.

Comment: @PeterMortensen not exactly, that question talks about using grep and other unix tools, which would require some inline conversion (for example via sed). This question is purely about using diff, where arguments to `diff` are the best solution.

Answer (score 216, accepted):

Use the `--strip-trailing-cr` option:

```
diff --strip-trailing-cr file1 file2
```

The option causes `diff` to strip the trailing carriage return character before comparing the files.

Comment: Thanks! I tried using `diff -w` which gave similar results but this is the most correct answer.

Comment: This still shows a difference on a change between Allman and 1TBS bracing style.

Comment: For some reason I misread this as `--skip-trailing-cr` instead of `--strip-trailing-cr`. I hope this comment is helpful to somebody!

Comment: This doesn't work in conjunction with the -y (side-by-side) option.  Trailing CR's are not ignored.

Comment: @Flimm remember - "strip before you skip" :)