# python subprocess.run(['diff', path1, path2], stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL) function shows difference between two files even when there isn't any

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to debug a python code.

Currently, I have two output files at two different paths: path1 and path2

Path2 has the following output:

```
price1,size1,price2,size2
100,100,0,0
```

Path1 has the following output:

```
price1,size1,price2,size2
100,100,0,0
```

The output for path2 is created this way:

```
with open(r'path2.csv', 'w+', newline='') as csvfile:
     csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
     fields = ['price1', 'size1', 'price2', 'size2']
     csvwriter.writerow(fields)
     row = [100, 100, 0, 0]
     csvwriter.writerow(row)
```

Path1.csv already exists and I have the following unit test function to compare the path1.csv content with path2.csv:

```
cmd = subprocess.run(["diff", path1.csv, path2.csv], stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL)
self.assertEqual(cmd.returncode, 0)
```

Here, I get the error:

```
AssertionError: 1 != 0
```

The subprocess command is intended to test the difference between the two files. It shows a difference even when there isn't any between the two files. I would love to know why this is happening? I have been stuck on this for a while now.

Any help regarding this would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Edit:
The following piece of code showed no difference between the files and difflib python library showed no difference as well. But I still the assertion error I mentioned above when I use the subprocess.run ().

```
with open(path1.csv, 'r') as t1, open(path2.csv, 'r') as t2:
    fileone = t1.readlines()
    filetwo = t2.readlines()

    for line in filetwo:
       if line not in fileone:
          print(line)
```

Comment: What's the output when you set `stdout=subprocess.PIPE` instead?

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy Thanks for the reply! The output is CompletedProcess(args=['diff', 'path1.csv', path2.csv'], returncode=1, stdout=b'1,2c1,2\n< bid_price,bid_size,ask_price,ask_size\n< 100,100,0,0\n---\n> bid_price,bid_size,ask_price,ask_size\r\n> 100,100,0,0\r\n')

There appears to be a difference in the end of line characters. Any suggestions on how to deal with it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I ignore line endings when comparing files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40974170/how-can-i-ignore-line-endings-when-comparing-files)

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy I don't have write permissions on the unit tests themselves. So, I cannot change the diff functions. I must make path2.csv be identical in format to path1.csv when writing to path2.csv.

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy Thanks for your help. I was able to figure out the problem. I added lineterminator="\n" parameter to csv.writer() and it seems to have fixed the issue.